# A volume integral question

Tags: integration, volume

When the region enclosed by the graphs of $y = 2x$ and $y = 6x-x^2$ is revolved around the $y-axis$, **the volume of the solid generated by is given by?**

Comment: I know at x=0 and x=4, y1=y2. And  y=6x-x^2 is above y=2x for this interval. It seems it should be solved by some 'dy' integrals but I got incorrect answer anyway..

Comment: It can be solved by slicing (a "$dy$ integral"). However, that involves solving for $x$ in terms of $y$ to find one of the radii, doable but slightly unpleasant. Cylindrical shells are easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graphs intersect at $x=0,4$. Hence, by the shell method,
$$V=2\pi\int^4_0x\left((6x-x^2)-(2x)\right)dx=2\pi\int^4_0\left(4x^2-x^3\right)dx$$
You can do the integral.